# How to vertically align lists when one li is a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make something like this (all centered throught the middle):

[image]

Here's my HTML and CSS that I'm currently using.

```
#header {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#666;
    text-align: center;
}

#header .navimg {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url(../images/header_img.png) no-repeat;
}

#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header ul li {
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

And the HTML.

```
<div id="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a</li>
        <li><div class="navimg"></div></li>
        <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Durka Durk</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I get this when I try to run it though.

[image]

How can I get what I wanted in the picture above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#header ul li {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Psvd5/)